# Multiple quotes in comments with replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to transform this:

```
[quote=mvneobux]My first comment[/quote]
I liked your comment.
```

In that:

```
<div class="quote">
    <div class="author">mvneobux:</div>
    My first comment.
</div>
I liked your comment.
```

the solution date in another topic works perfectly when there is only one quote. but two quotes or more don't work.

The current code is as follows

```
comment.replace(/\[quote=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/, '<div class="quote"><div class="author"> $1 </div> $2 </div>');
```

but in the following scenario the result is broken:

```
[quote=username2][quote=mvneobux]interessante e bom continue[/quote][/quote]
```

How can I solve? remembering that there may be several quotes within each other. How could I take each one separately?

Comment: Do you really mean `[quote=username2][quote=mvneobux]interessante e bom continue[/quote][/username2]`, or do you mean `[quote=username2][quote=mvneobux]interessante e bom continue[/quote][/quote]`? I'd think `[/quote]` would be the ending tag

Comment: Exactly, I typed it wrong. I just corrected it. Thanks for notifying

Comment: Would you like something like this:
`[[mvneobux:My first comment]I liked your comment.]`, and
`[username2:[mvneobux:interessante e bom continue]]`?
* here, the `[` and `]` are in place of `<div...>` and `</div>`, and
the outer set is the containing `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.*?` to match the content in the middle, match anything *but* `[quote=SOMETHING]` with `((?:(?!\[quote).)*?)`. Then, replace one at a time, until there are no more matches:

```js
let str = `[quote=mvneobux][quote=charlote]parabens pelo relato[/quote] legal seu relato[/quote]interessante`;

const pattern = /\[quote=([^\]]+)\]((?:(?!\[quote).)*?)\[\/quote\]/;
while (pattern.test(str)) {
  str = str.replace(pattern, '<div class="quote"><div class="author">$1</div>$2</div>');
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do this without using while?

Comment: Not exactly, since you don't know how many replacements will have to be made before the end until you get to the end

Comment: @1001SongsClips You could use a `for` loop instead of `while`, or some other similar method, but any such method will require an uncertain number of iterations until there aren't any more matches - for which `while` is perfectly suited for

Comment: Sorry confused your post with mine... I was like what the heck ...XD

Comment: I am testing with while but it is not working. It returns only the first format element, the second it does not find. Isn't it due to the spaces and comments in the second comment? For example:
``[quote=mvneobux][quote=charlote]parabens pelo relato[/quote] legal seu relato[/quote]interessante``

Comment: My code: 
`` getComment(){
                const pattern = /\[quote=([^\]]+)\]((?:(?!\[quote).)*?)\[\/quote\]/;
                while(pattern.test(this.getCommentNoHtml)){
                    this.getCommentNoHtml = this.comment.replace(pattern, '<div class="quote"><div class="author"> $1 </div> $2 </div>');
                }
                return this.getCommentNoHtml;
            }``

Comment: the error is occurring when there are lines with white space. How do I solve this?

Comment: @1001SongsClips I think your original code (and mine) had an extra `$2` at the end that was making things wonky - check things out now, I think it's producing the right output?

Comment: including ``'s``' at the end of the regex solved the problem. Like this: ``const pattern = /\[quote=([^\]]+)\]((?:(?!\[quote).)*?)\[\/quote\]/s;``

Answer (score 0):

Another options is just creating a simpler RegEx expression and use a simple replace in combination like

```js
    let result = `[quote=mvneobux]My first comment[/quote]
    I liked your comment.`
      .replace(/\[quote=(.+?)\]/,"<div class='author'>$1<div>")
      .replace("[/quote]", "<div>");
    
    console.log(result);
```